# Magento2: Phtml file not visible on PDP

Tags: magento2, blocks, phtml

I have create a module which consists an extra button on the product description page . For this I have added a layout catalog_product_view.xml which is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Test_ClickToCollect::js/product/view/clickToCollect.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block
                class="Test\ClickToCollect\Block\Product\View"
                name="product.info.clicktocollect"
                template="Test_ClickToCollect::product/view/pdpClick.phtml"
                after="product.info" ifconfig="click_to_collect/general/enable"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I do have created the respective block file and the template but my phmtl file is not rendered on the PDP . May I know why is this happening. As you can see I have added a js file as well in my layout which is rendering perfectly , but the phtml file is not. Also please note that I have removed the var/ generated/ pub/static/ did content:deploy but have no luck.

Comment: which potion you want to call your phtml file ??

Comment: below add to cart button

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Test_ClickToCollect::js/product/view/clickToCollect.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom">
            <block
                class="Test\ClickToCollect\Block\Product\View"
                name="product.info.clicktocollect"
                template="Test_ClickToCollect::product/view/pdpClick.phtml"
                after="product.info.addtocart" ifconfig="click_to_collect/general/enable"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Am I suppose to close the container using reference block? Is it fisible?

Comment: sorry its my mistake check updated answer

Comment: May I know what is the difference between my file and yours?

Comment: check answer...

Comment: No luck. I pasted the below code in one of the extended catalog_product_view.xml file which resides in app/design it worked . But I want it to work from my module only. Please note the code which I have pasted in the file.```<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block
        class="Test\ClickToCollect\Block\Product\View"
        name="product.info.clicktocollect"
        template="Test_ClickToCollect::product/view/pdpClick.phtml"
        after="product.info" ifconfig="click_to_collect/general/enable"/>
</referenceContainer> ```

Comment: please attach code which file or which potion to add my code